# Image detection and tracking on a video using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have an inverted pendulum video [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1lf1qvqq26ktan/inverted-pendulum.avi) which is 33 second length. The objective is to plot  a red point in the center of moving rectangle part of the pendulum and to plot a line along the black stick calculating its angle for every frame.

I have handled the video frame by frame. Then I have used [Object Detection In A Cluttered Scene Using Point Feature Matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html). It would be good if I had access to the matching point's indexes and then I would easily calculate the angle.

I have thought that I can get the moving rectangle part's region and seek the similar regions in the next frames. But this solution seems too local.

I do not know which techniques to apply.

```
clear all;
clc;

hVideoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader;
hVideoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

hVideoFileReader.Filename = 'inverted-pendulum.avi';

hVideoFileReader.VideoOutputDataType = 'single';

while ~isDone(hVideoFileReader)

    grayFrame = rgb2gray(step(hVideoFileReader)); 
    frame = step(hVideoFileReader); 

    if isFirstFrame
        part = grayFrame(202:266,202:282); % #moving part's region
        isFirstFrame = false;
        subplot(1,2,1);
        imshow(part);
    end

    partPoints = detectSURFFeatures(part);
    grayFramePoints = detectSURFFeatures(grayFrame);


    hold on;
    subplot(1,2,1),    plot(partPoints .selectStrongest(10));    
    subplot(1,2,2),    imshow(grayFrame);

    subplot(1,2,2),    plot(grayFramePoints .selectStrongest(20));


    frame2 = pointPendulumCenter(frame);  

    frame3 = plotLineAlongStick(frame2); 

    step(hVideoPlayer, frame3); 


    hold off;

end

release(hVideoFileReader);
release(hVideoPlayer);


%% #Function to find the moving part's center point and plot a red dot on it.
function f = pointPendulumCenter(frame)
end

%% #Function to plot a red line along the stick after calculating the angle of it.
function f = plotLineAlongStick(frame)
end
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the code you have posted just reads the video and runs `findCenterofRectangle(frame)` and `plotLineAlongStick(frame)`. It would be nice if you could add an mcve where you show (maybe with two images) how far you have got. You should post the code for those functions. The code you present doesn't add much value. Also, add some static images that people can work with, add some other images where you e.g. draw by hand to show exactly what you are trying to acheive. I think you need to narrow your question down quite a bit as it is quite broad at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It would make the problem much easier if your camera did not move. If you take your video with a stationary camera (e.g. mounted on a tripod) then you can use `vision.ForegroundDetector` to segment out moving objects from the static background.

Comment: camera is not completely stationary. It moves a little bit

Comment: I have tried `vsion.ForegroundDetector`. It draws white rectangles around moving segments. But I cannot know which rectangle is to be manupulated. I just need to plot a red dot onto the center of the moving part and a red line along the dark stick. I have updated my code. Maybe you want to take a look. Regards.

Comment: Can you determine which segment you need by size or shape?  The `regionprops` function lets you compute all kinds of shape features.